# Regrouping data by matching values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have no idea if what I'm looking for has a proper name or common way of addressing.
I have a table with 2 columns. 1st one is a key, other one one match of that key :

```
key-match

1 - 2
1 - 3
2 - 3
3 - 5
...
```

What I'd like to generate is a list of grouped chains.
For instance, in my data, there can be 10 lines with 1 as a key and 1 different match per row. BUT, if 1 matches with 2,3 and 3 matches with 5 and 5 matches with 16, the actual line should be :

```
1,2,3,5,16
```

In other words : all values that have a match, even non direct, should be grouped

I have absolutely no idea of how to achieve this, any help will be welcome !

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @forpas One column with one actual "cluster" per line

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store numbers in strings!  Don't store multiple values in a string!

Comment: first thing I'd do is to normalize your data storing only one value per row. So you will end up with 1-2 1-6 1-18 2-3 3-2 3-5 3-7 where every x-x is a row in your database. Then you can start analyzing your data

Comment: Actually @LelioFaieta that's what my source data is like ! But even like that I don't really know where to start :(

Comment: *One column with one actual "cluster" per line* meaning? Edit your question with the expected result, for this sample data, in tabular format.

Comment: edit your question to show your sample data (real structure) and expected result.

Comment: Just done @LelioFaieta

Comment: Just done @forpas

Comment: ... expected result must match sample data fully. Not "like", not partially...

Comment: Looks like reachability matrix building from connectivity matrix. Can be easily solved using recursive CTE.

Comment: You are probably looking for a recursive query. This is available in MySQL as of version 8: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html